# How to filter a genome assembly consistsing of a large number of contigs?

Tags: genome, assembly

I did some de novo genome assemblies with Illumina PE data using SPAdes, whereas most of them consisting of a large number of contigs(>1000). I have several questions below.

1. Do we need to filter short contigs?
2. How to determine the appropriate length threshold？

Comment: Hi, YP CHEN, could I know what kind of genome it is? bacterial? viral? eukaryotic? How long is the genome?

Comment: Fungal genomes， genome sizes are about ~ 50M

Comment: Thanks. I can't help in that case. But I guess what determines your length threshold is what use you intend to make from that assembly.